# Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to serialize default value of type Tuple2

Tags: apache-flink

When I run the official demo，it's not work

**code url**: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/quickstart/run_example_quickstart.html#writing-a-flink-program

```
package wikiedits;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FoldFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.functions.KeySelector;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.KeyedStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time.Time;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.wikiedits.WikipediaEditEvent;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.wikiedits.WikipediaEditsSource;

public class WikipediaAnalysis {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StreamExecutionEnvironment see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

    DataStream<WikipediaEditEvent> edits = see.addSource(new WikipediaEditsSource());

    KeyedStream<WikipediaEditEvent, String> keyedEdits = edits
      .keyBy(new KeySelector<WikipediaEditEvent, String>() {
        @Override
        public String getKey(WikipediaEditEvent event) {
          return event.getUser();
        }
      });

    DataStream<Tuple2<String, Long>> result = keyedEdits
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5))
      .fold(new Tuple2<>("", 0L), new FoldFunction<WikipediaEditEvent, Tuple2<String, Long>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Long> fold(Tuple2<String, Long> acc, WikipediaEditEvent event) {
          acc.f0 = event.getUser();
          acc.f1 += event.getByteDiff();
          return acc;
        }
      });

    result.print();

    see.execute();
  }
}
```

**run command:**

```
$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=wikiedits.WikipediaAnalysis
```

**run result:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Cannot serialize operator object class org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.operators.windowing.WindowOperator.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.setStreamOperator(StreamConfig.java:187)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.setVertexConfig(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:322)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createChain(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:216)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createChain(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:207)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.setChaining(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:177)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createJobGraph(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:126)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.getJobGraph(StreamGraph.java:580)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1170)
    at wikiedits.WikipediaAnalysis.main(WikipediaAnalysis.java:42)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to serialize default value of type Tuple2.
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.state.StateDescriptor.writeObject(StateDescriptor.java:334)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1128)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:512)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.writeObjectToConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:442)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.setStreamOperator(StreamConfig.java:184)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.state.StateDescriptor.writeObject(StateDescriptor.java:326)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this example running from the command line by removing the provided scope on the flink dependencies. Those four dependencies need to exactly match what's shown in the documentation (which obviously needs to be clearer on this point):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-wikiedits_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: thanks for your attention，i have found the problem，The reason is that my Maven downloaded the damaged jar package of flink-streaming-java_2.11-1.5.1.jar. Finally, I downloaded jar myself and put it into the maven repository.